Every numerical Semigroup is finitely generated
Before we delve into the question, let's begin with the following definition:

Let $S$ be a submonoid of $\mathbb{N}$. Then $S$ is a numerical semigroup if $\mathbb{N}-S$ is a finite set, equivalently, if the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $S$ contains $1$ (i.e., $1 \in \langle S \rangle$).

Now, we say that the numerical semigroup $S$ is finitely generated by $A \subseteq S$ if every element of $S$ can be written as a linear combination of elements of $A$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{N}$.
My aim is to prove that every numerical semigroup $S$ is finitely generated. To do this, I read the following proof from the book "Numerical Semigroups and Applications":
Let $A$ be a system of generators of $S$, and let $m$ be the multiplicity of $S$ (the smallest nonzero element of $S$). Then clearly, $m \in A$. Now, assume that $a \leq a'$ are two elements of $A$ such that $a \equiv a' \pmod{m}$. Then $a' = km + a$ for some $k$. So we can remove $a'$ from $A$, and we still have a generating system for $S$. At the end of this process, we have at most one element in $A$ in each congruence class modulo $m$, and we can choose $A$ to have finitely many elements.
I understand everything in this proof except the last sentence. How does it become finite after removing $a'$? Please, I need someone to make it clear to me or explain it in their own way. Thank you in advance.

Your definiton is unclear in two respects. Firstly, does ${\mathbb N}$ contain $0$? Secondly, what is the operation of the monoid ${\mathbb N}$?

The operation is the usual addition, and yes of course it contains zero.

It wouldn't become finite after removing a single element if it was infinite to begin with. But you could do the proof by contradiction. You can assume (by the well-ordering axiom) that $S$ is minimal with respect to containment. Then if $S$ is infinite, it must have two elements in the same congruence class, and you can remove one of them,  contradicting the minimality of $S$.

I don't quite grasp the concept. If it's infinite, why are there only two elements in the same congruence class?

I didn't say "only two", I meant at least two.

I understand that there may be more than two, but what I mean is, how can I visualize mathematically why, if it's infinite, we can find such a pair of elements?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Here is a more constructive proof that avoids considering infinite generating sets. Let
$$I = \{ i : i \in \{0,1,\ldots,m-1\} \mid \exists k \in S \setminus \{0\}: k \equiv i \bmod m \},$$
and for each $i \in I$ let $a_i$ be the least nonzero element of $S$ with $a_i \equiv i \bmod m$. So, in particular, $a_0 = m$.
Then by the argument in your proof, every element of $S$ is of the form $a_i + k a_0$ for some $i \in I$ and $k \in {\mathbb N}$, and so $S$ is generated by $A = \{a_i : i \in I \}$.
